# Windows 10 Professional - Disable Taskbar

Tags: windows, windows-10, taskbar, kiosk

I've been trying to do this a number of ways, I want to start up basically in kiosk mode for my home touch screen PC.

I'm using software that loads at startup, but is very old - it can't be made full screen or moved or anything like that. Anyway, once it loads, the task bar loads with a flashing orange icon, which is damn annoying as I have to get up and hit the icon to make the taskbar autohide again.

So I want to disable the taskbar completely. Preferably without a full shell replacement, but if that's what it takes, let me know a recommended alternative shell.

I've read a few guides for older versions of Windows, but none seem to work. I don't want the taskbar AT ALL, but I still want to be able to run start up scripts/applications.

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

1. Run your shell / app / manager at start-up.
2. End task explorer.exe (can be a startup delayed task) and set it not to auto-relaunch.

Not having explorer on active tasks will do exactly that: remove the task bar completely.

Alternate way:

There is also a REG key that tells windows what shell to load at start-up:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon
```

Put your shell there instead of explorer. It will have the same effect: no taskbar.

Comment: The alternate way is the way to go IMHO.

Comment: Agreed, if the replacement shell can launch explorer in an easy manner if needed.